# Scanf before the switch/case won't work.

Tags: c, arrays, scanf

The scanf before the switch/case function is never used and it completely stops the program.
    Althought I'm also not sure if the functions work since i haven't been able to properly run the program. I just want for the scanf to work properly. It is probably some dumb mistake like always but if you anyone could help me find out why it wont even prompt for an input then i would be very grateful. Any other corrections to the rest of the code would also be greatly appreciated.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #define Max_Numbers 50//defined max array size

    float CalcAverage(float list[],  int numbers);//function to calulate average
    int Minimum(float list[], int numbers);//calculates minimum
    int Maximum(float list[], int numbers);//calculate max
    float StandDev(float list[], int numbers);//calculates standard deviation


    int main()
    {
        int numbers;
        float output;
        int idx;
        char option;
        float list[Max_Numbers];
        printf("Enter the amount of numbers you wish to input:\n");
        scanf ("%d", &numbers);//prompting for size of array
        if(numbers > Max_Numbers)
        {
            printf("Too many numbers\n");// im not really sure how to get this to work as well
            return -1;
        }
        for (idx = 0; idx < numbers; idx++)//counter for entered values
        {
            printf("Enter a number\n");
            scanf("%d", &list[idx]);
        }

        printf("What would you like to do?\n");
        printf("(1): Calculate Average\n");          //menu options to determine which 
        printf("(2): Calculate Maximum\n");          //function will be used
        printf("(3): Calculate Minimum\n");
        printf("(4): Calculate Standard Deviation\n");
        printf("Enter menu option:\n");

        scanf("%c", &option);//scanf for menu options, program stops before this scanf

        switch (option)//I believe the program is breaking at this switch
        {
            case ('1'):
                output = CalcAverage(list, numbers);//calls to CalcAverage
                break;
            case ('2'):
                output = Maximum(list, numbers);//calls to Maximum
                break;
            case ('3'):
                output = Minimum(list, numbers);//Calls to minimum
                break;
            case ('4'):
                output = StandDev(list, numbers);//calls to StandDev
                break;
            default:
                printf("Invalid menu option\n");\\default option in case wrong value entered
                break;
        }
        printf("The result is %.2f", output);// the result 
    }

    float CalcAverage(float list[],  int numbers)//function definition for average
    {
        int idx;
        float sum = 0;
        float result;
        for(idx = 0; idx < numbers; idx++)//counter used to add all values
        {
            sum = sum + list[idx];
        }
        result = (float) sum / numbers;
        return result;
    }
    int Maximum(float list[], int numbers)//function def. for max
    {
        int idx;
        int maximum = 0;
        for(idx = 0; idx < numbers; idx++)//counter used to compare values
        {
            if (maximum < list[idx])      //im not sure if i wrote some of 
            {                             //these functions correctly
                maximum = list[idx];      //The main problem i have is
            }                             //that scanf that breaks the 
        }                                 //program
        return maximum;

    }
    int Minimum(float list[], int numbers)//fun def. for min
     {
        int idx;
        int minimum = 0;
        for(idx = 0; idx < numbers; idx++)
        {
            if (minimum > list[idx])
            {
                minimum = list[idx];
            }
        }
        return minimum;

    }
    float StandDev(float list[], int numbers)//function def. for standard deviation
    {
       int idx;
      float avg;
      float newlist[numbers];
      float newavg;
      avg = CalcAverage(list, numbers);
     for(idx = 0; idx < numbers; idx++)
       {
           newlist[idx] = (list[idx] - avg) * (list[idx] - avg);//Is this the proper way to put those            
       }                                                        //values in the new array?

       newavg = CalcAverage(newlist, numbers);
       return sqrt(newavg);

    }
```

Comment: It's `'\n'` that is left in the buffer after reading an `int`. Add space before `%c` (use `" %c"`) and try again.

Comment: wooooowww thank you so much! i feel like an idiot

Comment: You can use `float list[numbers];` just after `scanf ("%d", &numbers);` to get rid of `if(numbers > Max_Numbers){ … }`. And functions `Maximum` and `Minimum` should be designed to handle `float`s, not `int`s.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &list[idx]);` won't work as you wish as list[idx] is not an int.

Comment: So, change the return type of those functions as well as the type of `maximum` and `minimum` to `float` and initialize them to `FLT_MIN` and `FLT_MAX` respectively after including `limits.h`.

Comment: "_`//Is this the proper way to put those            
                                                            //values in the new array?`_" -- Yes.

Comment: thank you all so much. i did the changes you guys said, althought the minimum function is returning zero each time as well, max and avg worked, i still need to check stand dev

Comment: Post the corrected code.